# Keep Deus Ex and DLC installations if I have the Director's Cut?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I have Deus Ex: Human Revolution and the Missing Link DLC in Steam.
Now I have bought the Director's Cut.

The Director's Cut adds an other entry in the Steam library and requires additional space on the disk.

Are there reasons to keep the installations of the original game and the DLC?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a game in progress in the old release of DXHR you will have to finish it there, as the new release does not accept old saves. Other than that the only reason to keep DXHR along with DXHRDC is if you prefer the old release to the new one.